# specify minOccurence and maxOccurence with jaxb annotations

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

How do I specify minOccurence and maxOccurence for the collection(list) in .java file with jaxb annotations?

Comment: I have entered an enhancement bug ( https://bugs.eclipse.org/345787 ) to track this feature request in the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation.  Please feel free update the bug with additional details.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  JAXB annotations have only a very minimal set of validation abilities.

If you need to perform validation at runtime, you need to use an XML Schema for this.  If you need to *generate* an XML Schema from Java, then you need to alter it after you generate it, to add the various bits of tight validation that you need.

Comment: Can binding files used for specifying these advanced validations?